# Кнопка, не меняющая своего положения при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Здравствуй ХешКод, скажите, мне нужно сделать кнопку, которая всегда находится в экране, при скроле вниз, вверх неважно эту кнопку было видно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>
.test {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 5px;
   right: 5px;
}
</style>

<div class="test">кнопка</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично работает!!